# Unable to use microphone in BrowserStack

Tags: browserstack

I was testing one my site using browser stack, but got stuck on web calling. I want to call through my application but its not taking audio input from the microphones, I have given the permissions as well as tried checking using chrome voice search. Can anyone let me know how to enable that feature there ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that support for integrating the local machine's microphone with the remote device microphone is unavailable on BrowserStack.